# Python Selenium + Datepicker Click

Tags: python, selenium, datepicker, scrapy

I have been banging my head around trying to get the price of a room like [this](https://www.homeaway.pt/arrendamento-ferias/p1418427a?uni_id=1590648) for example by clicking the first available (green) datepicker checkin input and then clicking the first available datepicker checkout input so the price for the minium period is generated.

My code is a mess so i would really appreciate if someone could post a cleaner code to achieve that.

I am using Python selenium + scrapy although something in Java for example would still help.

UPDATE:

here is the code:

```
def availability(self, doc):
    url = doc['url'] + '#calendar'
    self.driver.get(url)
    is_active = True
    # We want to the availability/price for each day in a month.
    availabilities = []

    # wait for the check in input to load
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)

    try:
        elem = wait.until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".dates-group input[name=startDateInput]")
            )
        )
    except TimeoutException:
        pass
    else:
        elem.click()  # open calendar
        # wait for datepicker to load
        wait.until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.ui-datepicker:not(.loading)'))
        )
        days = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
            "#ui-datepicker-div tr td"
        )

        for cell in days:
            day = cell.text.strip()
            if not day:
                continue

            if "full-changeover" not in cell.get_attribute("class"):
                available = False
            else:
                available = True

            self.logger.warning('CELL "%s"', cell)
            self.logger.warning('DAY "%s"', day)
            self.logger.warning('available "%s"', available)


        # The first iteration was to list the availability, now we want to
        # click the first available element to get the price
        for cell in days:
            day = cell.text.strip()
            if not day:
                continue

            if "full-changeover" in cell.get_attribute("class"):
                self.logger.warning('CLICK IT "%s"', day)
                self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
                x = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td/a[text()=" + day + "]")
                self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
                x.click() # Element not found in the cache issue here
                # import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()

            # self.logger.warning('CELL "%s"', cell)
            # self.logger.warning('DAY "%s"', day)
            # self.logger.warning('available "%s"', available)

        # elem.click()  # close checkin calendar

        # Now lets click on the checkout input to get the price and minimum
        # number of days. We probably don't have to wait for the checkout
        # because its already loaded but you never know.

        try:
            elem = wait.until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                    (By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                     ".dates-group input[name=endDateInput]")
                )
            )
        except TimeoutException:
            pass
        else:
            # elem.click()  # open calendar in checkout input
            # wait for datepicker to load
            wait.until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.ui-datepicker:not(.loading)'))
            )
            days = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
                "#ui-datepicker-div tr td"
            )

            for cell in days:
                day = cell.text.strip()
                if not day:
                    continue

                # This is the first available date to checkout
                if "full-changeover" in cell.get_attribute("class"):
                    self.logger.warning('CLICK IT "%s"', available)
                    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
                    # Here we would get the generated price



                self.logger.warning('CELL "%s"', cell)
                self.logger.warning('DAY "%s"', day)
                self.logger.warning('available "%s"', available)




        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()

    return {'availabilities': availabilities, 'is_active': is_active}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you post what you have so far? At least, relevant parts..

Comment: @alecxe i added the code

Comment: @alecxe by the way this is just what i thought would be right to make it work, if you have a better idea please let me know. I started getting `Element not found in the cache` on the click thats how i realized i was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One tricky thing about this calendar is that you first need to hover a particular day and then relocate the active day and click it. Here is a working implementation that selects the first available start and end dates and prints the calculated price:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = 'https://www.homeaway.pt/arrendamento-ferias/p1418427a?uni_id=1590648'
driver.get(url)

# pick start date
start_date = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".quotebar-container input[name=startDateInput]")))
start_date.click()

first_available_date = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ui-datepicker-div td.full-changeover > a")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(first_available_date).perform()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ui-datepicker-div td.full-selected.full-changeover > a").click()

# pick end date (TODO: violates DRY principle, refactor!)
end_date = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".quotebar-container input[name=endDateInput]")))
end_date.click()

first_available_date = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ui-datepicker-div td.full-changeover > a")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(first_available_date).perform()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ui-datepicker-div td.full-selected.full-changeover > a").click()

# get the calculated price
price = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".price-quote .price-total")))
print(price.text)

driver.close()
```

At the moment, it selects `20/04/2016` and `23/04/2016` and prints `180€`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: let me try this tonight and ill come mark it right after :)

Comment: it works :) .. thanks again for your help spent a whole afternoon trying to figure this out

Comment: hi alecxe , with this solution how can i get the availability for the folowing months? i am trying to click on the calendar next button after the first start_date click with `self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.ui-datepicker-next.ui-corner-all').click()` but i am getting a `ElementNotVisibleException` any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Comment: @psychok7 hey, would you be okay to create a separate question? More users would have a chance to help. I'll definitely take a look, throw me a link here. Thanks!

Comment: here is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010064/getting-availability-from-datepicker-for-x-months . I am having trouble with 2 different sites but the code is all there