# Getting availability from datepicker for x months for a site

Tags: python, selenium, datepicker

i am trying to get the availability/price for each day in airbnb by clicking the next button in the datepicker calendar but with no luck.

My current code is something like:

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    def airbnb():
        display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
        display.start()
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get("https://www.airbnb.pt/rooms/265820")

        # wait for the check in input to load
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        elem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.book-it-panel input[name=checkin]")))
        elem.click()

        # wait for datepicker to load
        wait.until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.ui-datepicker:not(.loading)'))
        )

        days = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".ui-datepicker table.ui-datepicker-calendar tr td")
        for cell in days:
            day = cell.text.strip()
            if not day:
                continue

            if "ui-datepicker-unselectable" in cell.get_attribute("class"):
                status = "Unavailable"
            else:
                status = "Available"

            price = "n/a"
            if status == "Available":
                # hover the cell and wait for the tooltip
                ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(cell).perform()
                price = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.datepicker-tooltip'))).text

            print(day, status, price)
```

They both work but only for 1 month. I want to be able to set X months instead. For example for homeaway i tried with `self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.ui-datepicker-next.ui-corner-all').c‌​lick()` right after the first open calendar click but i got a `ElementNotVisibleException`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would locate the "next month" button with `a.ui-datepicker-next` CSS selector which is both readable and reliable.

Here is the implementation - processing as many months as the `MONTH_COUNT` variable defines:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


MONTH_COUNT = 3

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.airbnb.pt/rooms/265820")

# wait for the check in input to load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
elem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.book-it-panel input[name=checkin]")))
elem.click()

# iterate over the month count
for month in range(MONTH_COUNT):
    # wait for datepicker to load
    wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.ui-datepicker:not(.loading)'))
    )

    # getting current month for displaying purposes
    current_month = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".ui-datepicker-month").text
    print(current_month)

    # iterate over days
    days = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".ui-datepicker table.ui-datepicker-calendar tr td")
    for cell in days:
        day = cell.text.strip()
        if not day:
            continue

        if "ui-datepicker-unselectable" in cell.get_attribute("class"):
            status = "Unavailable"
        else:
            status = "Available"

        price = "n/a"
        if status == "Available":
            # hover the cell and wait for the tooltip
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(cell).perform()
            price = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.datepicker-tooltip'))).text

        print(day, status, price)

    print("-----")
    # click next month
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.ui-datepicker-next").click()

driver.close()
```

Prints:

```
Maio
(u'1', 'Unavailable', 'n/a')
(u'2', 'Unavailable', 'n/a')
(u'3', 'Unavailable', 'n/a')
...
(u'30', 'Unavailable', 'n/a')
(u'31', 'Unavailable', 'n/a')
-----
Junho
(u'1', 'Unavailable', 'n/a')
(u'2', 'Unavailable', 'n/a')
(u'3', 'Unavailable', 'n/a')
...
(u'28', 'Unavailable', 'n/a')
(u'29', 'Unavailable', 'n/a')
(u'30', 'Unavailable', 'n/a')
-----
Julho
(u'1', 'Unavailable', 'n/a')
(u'2', 'Unavailable', 'n/a')
(u'3', 'Unavailable', 'n/a')
...
(u'29', 'Unavailable', 'n/a')
(u'30', 'Available', u'\u20ac36')
(u'31', 'Available', u'\u20ac36')
-----
```

Comment: it works for airbnb but it seems to be more complicated for homeaway because we have to play around with 2 calendars to get the price.. do you have any sugestion for that one?

Comment: i tried adding a `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.ui-datepicker-next").click()` after the `first_available_date` and another after `end_date` and i get a `ElementNotVisibleException`

Comment: Do you want me to update my question with the full code i am trying for airbnb?

Comment: @psychok7 wait, you have difficulties with `homeaway` now or the code i've provided for airbnb? Thanks.

Comment: the question was for both airbnb and homeaway since i was having similar problems. you answered for airbnb and it works perfectly and i tried applying the same idea to the homeaway code (witch is in the description as well) but i am getting the erros i posted here in the comments

Comment: @psychok7 got it, sure. Would you be okay to resolve this topic with a working airbnb solution and create a new one and keep that homeaway specific? Make sure to provide all of the details needed. Thank you!

Comment: here is the link to the homeaway related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37030132/getting-availability-from-datepicker

Comment: hi, were you able to have a look at the other question related to homeaway that i posted? i am still having trouble with that one.

Comment: @psychok7 yeah, but I think you've already solved it yourself, correct? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah i did.. Thanks anyways