# Able to locate element in date picker, but click does not select the date

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to select a date from **date picker** using **selenium python**, I'm able to locate the current date, but click is not happening on that element. Can anyone help me to understand what is wrong?

```
res = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(),'24')]")))
print res.tag_name
print res.text
actions.double_click(res).perform()
print "bye"
```

I can see the result of `print res.tag_name`, `print res.text` and `print "bye"`. but `res.click()` did not select the date.
Below is the Outer-HTML code for the element.

```
<a href="javascript:winMain.document.getElementById('fromDate').value='24/8/2018';;window.close();">24</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Selenium + Datepicker Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723659/python-selenium-datepicker-click)